# United Airlines E-ticket and Pending transaction

Tags: air-travel, payment-cards, united-airlines

I bought a ticket from united airlines using my credit card and received an eticket. However, on the credit card online account the transaction shows up but it is on the pending list. Is that something I should worry about ?

Comment: When did you buy the ticket?  It is normal for any credit card transaction to appear as "pending" for the first few days - this is not specific to airlines or travel.

Comment: I bought the tickets 2 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that something I should worry about ?

Generally no. It can take a few days for the transaction to fully complete. If it's less than three days, I wouldn't worry. If it's more, you should follow up

You typically get two e-mails from United. The first one comes immediately after booking and typically says "your reservation is processing". The second one says "eTicket Itinerary and Receipt for Confirmation XXXXXX" and often comes just a few minutes later. Once you have the second one you have a confirmed reservation which is all you need for travel.

If your charge is still pending 72 hours after booking I would check the booking on the United website and make sure it's still ok. I doesn't harm to call them up and ask.

## How to check on United's website

1. Log into your account
2. Got to "My Trips", find your reservation and click "manage trip"
3. Right at the top of the page (but under the alerts) you will see something like

Confirmation number: J2LXXX
Ticket status:  ticketed Aug 15, 2021 at 4:48 PM Central Time

If you have a confirmation number (6 digits) and of the ticket stats says "ticketed", you are good to go.

Comment: If I am able to get eticket from United Airlines using their website after 72 hours does that mean the ticket is confirmed?

Comment: What do you mean "get eticket?" You should already have a confirmed reservation (which includes and e-ticket) regardless of whether the payment is still pending or not.

Comment: I already have an e-ticket. But if I go to the united's website using my confirmation number I can get the e-ticket mailed to me again. If I do that say 3 days and still get the eticket mailed to me does that the reservation is ok?

Comment: I see ticketed on my online status.

Comment: If it's ticketed, it's ok